# Passing values from a dictionary into a new column in a dataframe

Tags: python

I am working with the following df and dictionary

```
               Country    Population      Continent
0                China  1.367645e+09  South America
1        United States  3.176154e+08  South America
2                Japan  1.274094e+08  South America
3       United Kingdom  6.387097e+07  South America
4   Russian Federation  1.435000e+08  South America
5               Canada  3.523986e+07  South America
6              Germany  8.036970e+07  South America
7                India  1.276731e+09  South America
8               France  6.383735e+07  South America
9          South Korea  4.980543e+07  South America
10               Italy  5.990826e+07  South America
11               Spain  4.644340e+07  South America
12                Iran  7.707563e+07  South America
13           Australia  2.331602e+07  South America
14              Brazil  2.059153e+08  South America
```

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
```

What i am trying to do is to make is a new column called 'Continent', which it is created by matching the country with a key in the dictionary to retrieve its specific value (the continent)

```
for country in df['Country']:    
    df['Continent'] = ContinentDict[country]
```

However the problem is that I do not get the correct continent and as you can see in the df image, the whole column is filled with 'South America' ....

I am trying to get the correct continent for each country

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['Continent']=df['Country'].replace(ContinentDict)
```